# remove overlapping from images and make caption below image stretch across columns

Tags: css

I have been struggling with trying to make text sit correctly on the page. What I am trying to do is is be able to provide images and captions on this semi-calendar, but make the image and caption extend through multiple columns. Right now the image extends through multiple columns but the text does not. Also, the image overlaps the other and I want to prevent that as well.

```css
      .col1 {
            float: left;
            left: 5%;
        }

        .col2 {
            float: left;
            left: 15%;
        }

        .col3 {
            float: left;
            left: 35%;
        }

        .col4 {
            float: left;
            right: 35%;
   
        }

        .col5 {
            float: left;
            left: 75%;
        }

        .col6 {
            float: left;
            left: 95%;
        }

        .col7 {
            float: left;
            left: 100%;
        }

        .col8 {
            float: left;
            left: 90%;
        }

        .col9 {
            float: left;
            left: 90%;
        }

        div {
            display: inline;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 3px;
            margin: 6px;
            text-align: justify;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="col1">
        <strong>Jan</strong><br><br> No Training Due.
    </div>

    <div class="col2">
        <strong> Feb</strong><br><br> No Training Due.
    </div>

    <div class="col3">
        <strong> March</strong><br><br>No Training Due.
    </div>

    <div class="col4">
        <strong>Apr</strong><br><br> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff"/><span>The my class training opens Apr 16 - June 16. Open to All Associates</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col5">
        <strong>May</strong><br>    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/> Medicaid Compliance<br>
    </div>

    <div class="col6">
         <strong>June</strong><br> 
    </div>

    <div class="col7">
        July<br> multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images.
    </div>


    <div class="col8">
        Aug<br> multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images.
    </div>
    <div class="col9">
        Sep<br> multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images. multi-column layout with inline images.
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. You want images to span multiple columns, but not overlap what's in the adjoining columns? Then what _should_ happen to the content of the adjoining columns? Also, stupid question, but what is the meaning of all the `left` properties in  the css?

Comment: no worries..ive found a solution